# How to remove certain information from webscraping function (Beautiful Soup):

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape from this website https://lawyers.justia.com/lawyer/michael-paul-ehline-85006

I do not not want the sponsered listings in my output:

My code:

```
for o in soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "block-wrapper"}): 
    for de in o.findAll("li"):
        if de != []:
            de=remove_tags(str(de))
            print (de)
```

Output in python:
[OUTPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3hKU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete something within an HTML page. After you find using findAll('div', attrs={"class": "primary-sidebar-wrapper"}) the element that you need. You can do the following:

```
tag = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "block-wrapper"})
tag[0].replace_with("")
```

This replaces the HTML text in the variable soup as well